# dragover event in canvas doesn't fired on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

What I'm trying to do is a panel to add your image, which can be rotated, scaled, moved and cropped. The user should be able to move the image by dragging.

The application works well in Chrome, IE, Opera, and Safari but for some reason the drag doesn't work on Firefox. Debugging the code I see that the event `dragover` is not fired but the console doesn't show any errors so I really don't know what's wrong.

[Here's my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/justelnegro/Vykxf/31/)

Comment: Should I be able to drop an image onto the big `div`/`canvas`? Because in both Firefox 25 and Chrome 31, I'm seeing the window location change if you drop an image there.

Comment: you can add a image to the canvas and tried to move it, this will work on safari, chrome but not in firefox

Comment: It's a nice example of drag events. One comment though, I think `style.transform` has been un-prefixed in Mozilla (no longer `style.MozTransform`) since version 16 (almost a year old).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MDN's documentation of Drag operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations), you need to `setData` into the `dataTransfer` property of the `DragStart` event.

In your case, the function `CanvasMouseDown(e)` is the event handler for `#picture`'s `DragStart`, so somewhere in that function you should call:

```
e.dataTransfer.setData( datatype, datacontent );
```

Below, I have updated your example to set `text/plain`, which is sufficient for "just making it work", as you're *dragging* but not *dropping*. In the latter case, it would be more meaningful to set `image/xxx` where `xxx` is the appropriate format (e.g. `png` or `jpeg`).

[Working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vykxf/32/) (Verified with Firefox 25.0.1, Win 7 SP 1.)